Unable to make KeyTool in efitools: efi.h not included even though its included in makefile
When running sudo make KeyTool in efitools, an error appears even though they are all included:
bebo@DESKTOP-0PMMN4K:/usr/efitools$ sudo make KeyTool
cc -O2 -g  -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-stack-check -DGNU_EFI_USE_MS_ABI -DEFI_FUNCTION_WRAPPER -mno-red-zone -DCONFIG_x86_64 -nostdlib -shared -Bsymbolic /lib/crt0-efi-x86_64.o -L /lib -L /usr/lib -L /usr/lib64 -T elf_x86_64_efi.lds  KeyTool.c -lefi -lgnuefi /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libgcc.a  -o KeyTool
KeyTool.c:8:10: fatal error: efi.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include <efi.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: KeyTool] Error 1
bebo@DESKTOP-0PMMN4K:/usr/efitools$

I use WSL.
Only HelloWorld.c builded successfully.
I tried:
Changing the Make.rules and Makefile file to include gnu-efi. However, the module remains not included.
Adding GNU-EFI = [directory] to the make rules and makefile. However, it still does not include it.
Installing gnu-efi using apt.
Installing efitools using apt. This does not do anything.
Running sudo make clean.
What actually happened:
When building KeyTool.c, an error occurs stating that efi.h does not exist, even though it actually exists in the make rules, makefile, include directory, and /usr/include/efi.
Makefile
EFIFILES = HelloWorld.efi LockDown.efi Loader.efi ReadVars.efi UpdateVars.efi \
        KeyTool.efi HashTool.efi SetNull.efi ShimReplace.efi
BINARIES = cert-to-efi-sig-list sig-list-to-certs sign-efi-sig-list \
        hash-to-efi-sig-list efi-readvar efi-updatevar cert-to-efi-hash-list \
        flash-var

EFIINC          = /usr/include/efi

ifeq ($(ARCH),x86_64)
EFIFILES += PreLoader.efi
endif

INCLUDES=-I/usr/efitools/include/

GNU_EFI_DIR := /usr/efitools/include
GNU_EFI_DIR := ./gnu-efi-code

Not all of the code are included.
Make.rules
GNU_EFI_DIR := ./includes
ARCH     = $(shell uname -m | sed 's/i.86/ia32/;s/arm.*/arm/')
ifeq ($(ARCH),ia32)
ARCH3264 = -m32
else ifeq ($(ARCH),x86_64)
ARCH3264 =
else ifeq ($(ARCH),aarch64)
ARCH3264 =
else ifeq ($(ARCH),arm)
ARCH3264 =
else
$(error unknown architecture $(ARCH))
endif
INCDIR     = -I$(TOPDIR)include/ -I/usr/include/efi -I/usr/include/efi/$(ARCH) -I/usr/include/efi/protocol -I/usr/efitools/include
CPPFLAGS   = -DCONFIG_$(ARCH)
CFLAGS     = -O2 -g $(ARCH3264) -fpic -Wall -fshort-wchar -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-merge-constants -fno-stack-protector -ffreestanding -fno-st>LDFLAGS    = -nostdlib
CRTOBJ          = crt0-efi-$(ARCH).o
CRTPATHS        = /lib /lib64 /lib/efi /lib64/efi /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/include/efi /usr/lib64/efi /usr/lib/gnuefi /usr/lib64/gnuefi

